# Access BehaviorExtensionElement through configuration settings

Tags: wcf, configuration, workflow-foundation

I have workflow service with an extension that I configuration through a custom BehaviorExtensionElement.
Since I need to reuse some configuration properties also in other pieces of my application, I would like to know how it is possible to read the configuration element through the ConfigurationManager.

```
public class ServiceConfigurationElement : BehaviorExtensionElement
{
    public const string RetryDelayKey = "retryDelay";

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a behavior extension based on the current configuration settings.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// The behavior extension.
    /// </returns>
    protected override object CreateBehavior()
    {
        var behavior = new ServiceConfigurationBehavior
            {
                RetryDelay = this.CommsRetryDelay
            };
        return behavior;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the type of behavior.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>
    /// A <see cref="T:System.Type"/>.
    /// </returns>
    public override Type BehaviorType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(ServiceConfigurationBehavior);
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(RetryDelayKey, IsKey = false, DefaultValue = true)]
    public TimeSpan RetryDelay
    {
        get

        {
            return (TimeSpan)this[RetryDelayKey];
        }

        set
        {
            this[RetryDelayKey] = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And the configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior>
                <serviceConfiguration retryDelay="00:01:00" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <extensions>
        <behaviorExtensions>
            <add name="serviceConfiguration" type="MyNamespace.ConfigurationElement, MyAssembly"/>
        </behaviorExtensions>
    </extensions>
</system.serviceModel>
```

How can I read the RetryDelay property (and others, of course) through the ConfigurationManager?

Thanks

Francesco

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ConfigurationManager does not have a property explicitly for the ServiceModel section. Instead, Microsoft provided the ServiceModelSectionGroup ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.configuration.servicemodelsectiongroup.aspx)) which will allow you to retrieve that section to read values.

First you will need to load the configuration file using the various ways to open it on the ConfigurationManager ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)). Below I use the OpenMappedExeConfiguration method.

```
ExeConfigurationFileMap exeConfigurationFileMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap
{
    ExeConfigFilename = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location + ".config"
};
Configuration configuration = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration( exeConfigurationFileMap, ConfigurationUserLevel.None );
```

After that, you will need to retrieve the section by doing the following:

```
ServiceModelSectionGroup serviceModelGroup = ServiceModelSectionGroup.GetSectionGroup( configuration );
```

From there you can access any of the service model configuration values. I will modify your behavior to the following for an example. Note the named behavior.

```
<behavior name="Configuration">
    <serviceConfiguration retryDelay="00:01:00" />
</behavior>
```

Once you have the section group, it's just a matter of getting the behavior extensions and iterating through them, like so.

```
ServiceBehaviorElementCollection serviceBehaviors = serviceModelGroup.Behaviors.ServiceBehaviors;

foreach ( ServiceBehaviorElement behavior in serviceBehaviors )
{
    if ( behavior.Name == "Configuration" )
    {
        ServiceConfigurationElement serviceConfiguration = behavior[ typeof( ServiceConfigurationElement ) ] as ServiceConfigurationElement;
        Console.WriteLine( serviceConfiguration.RetryDelay.ToString() );
        // do whatever you like here
    }
}
```

You'll see that I used the ServiceBehaviors, but there is another property for the EndpointBehaviors as well. One way to extend this would be to cache the service model section group in a static variable (less disk I/O) and write a few methods to query the various attributes of any extensions you might write in the future.

Hope this helps!